# Windows Authentication with MVC. Windows Authentication with different "accesslevels"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, razor, windows-authentication

Im new to MVC and Authentication.

We are developing an MVC application that will be using Windows authentication. We first solved it by using razor in HTML like this:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("somerole") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("somerole") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("somerole"))
```

But this wont work in the long run since we want to be able to add/remove in the database that a certain windows auth should be able to see/not see a certain view. In other words we need it to be more flexible/dynamic then the example above.

Lets say that our database with Users looks something like this:

```
USER
string windowsauth
int accesslevel
```

If we then have a user with the windowsauth "Domain User" and accesslevel 1, I want that user to be able to see all the pages.

And another user with the windowsauth "Other user" with accesslevel 2 would only be able to see certain pages.

We dont have a clue how to solve this, I hope that my question is clear enough. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a base model that contains a list of authorised roles for the current view. Then you can do something like:

```
@if(Model.AuthRoles.Any(r=>HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(r))
```

So your base model could look like this:

```
public class BaseModel{
    List<string> AuthRoles {get;set;}

    public BaseModel(List<string> authorisedRoles){
        AuthRoles = authorisedRoles;
    }

    public BaseModel(){
         AuthRoles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Then when you are populating your model you can load the authorised roles from your database.

Perform a check on the roles at this point as well and do any necessary re-direct.

You could use a similar premise for constructing your Navigation Bar in your site.